# raising input child to parent Object

Tags: reactjs, react-props

My problem is that I want to raise my input child to parent object.
but whenever i type the input, it doesn't save to my state.
think the problem is in `pkp[index].Sasaran += question.Sasaran;` , how i should write that code. help me please..

parent component

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: [],
      selectedOption2: [],
      pkp: []
    };
   } 
handleChange = question => {
    const pkp = [...this.state.pkp];
    const index = pkp.indexOf(question);
    pkp[index] = { ...question };
    pkp[index].Sasaran = question.Sasaran;
    this.setState({ pkp });
    console.log(this.state.pkp);
  };
```

here my child component

```
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.question.SubVariabel}</td>
        <td>
          <input
            name="sasaran"
            type="number"
            onChange={() => this.props.onChange(this.props.question)}
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            name="capaian"
            type="number"
            onChange={() => this.props.onChange(this.props.question)}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value might actually be updating.

```
const pkp = [...this.state.pkp];
  const index = pkp.indexOf(question);
  pkp[index] = { ...question };
  pkp[index].Sasaran += question.Sasaran;
  this.setState({ pkp });
  console.log(this.state.pkp);
};
```

This `console.log(this.state.pkp)` will NOT show the new state. The setState is not immediate. The component needs to re-render with the new value before it shows in the state. Check the value somewhere else (like in the render) and maybe the update will show correctly.

Here are some more details about how the setState works behind the scenes: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have checked it with React Development tool of Chrome.

Comment: Is the handleChange being called correctly with the value then? The state just isn't updated? Do you have a `componentShouldUpdate` or another lifecycle method implemented that could be blocking the re-render with the new state value?

Comment: yeah, the handleChange called correctly, its result is an array. it just the state isn't updated. i have componentDidMount to call an previous array from firebase database. Should i post the whole code?

Comment: when i change the `pkp[index].Sasaran = 8` , the state changed correcly. so i suspicious the problem is on that code.

Comment: Try dropping the `+=` and make it explicit `pkp[index].Sasaran = pkp[index].Sasaran + pkp[index].Sasaran` maybe there is a reference issue with `+=` that is actually trying to mutate the value? Not sure. That is weird to me.

Comment: Nope, the state is still 0 (it doesn't changed)

Comment: When i change the `pkp[index].Sasaran ++' , the state increment correcly. but i want to get what client input.

Comment: If you are trying to use the input then you are not passing it in via the onChange. You should add the text to the onChange call in that case:          `onChange={e => this.props.onChange({this.props.question, e.target.value})}` and then `handleChange = (question, value)`